# Non-destructively joining meshes

Tags: mesh, modifiers

Blender has no object joining modifier. I think it would be useful to somehowe achievce it. Can anyone suggest a method for properly doing it? I would like to retain the objects transform, like when simply joining objects, but of course with all the previous modifiers and the two original editable meshes kept non-destructively.

Comment: what I do not see in that idea is : what do you want to do after that ? Adding another modifier (for instance an armature) ?

Comment: I asked this with a dual purpose in mind: To share my answere, because I think it is generally useful, and hoping to get a better answere. I have currenty no specific project where I need this, but it might get handy, when I want to use a buch of modifiers on separate objects.

Comment: And not having to adjust the modifiers for all the separate objects. Or add particles on the surface of the joined meshes, use them as one single solid rigidbody, etc.

Comment: Sounds like group instances could do what you want to achieve, check [my answer here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47295/sketchup-like-components-case-study-is-it-in-or-even-feasible) and see if it helps. You could create a separate scene to keep group definition originals, and then use group instances in your actual scene.

Answer (score 1):

## Array Modifier

If I want to join A with B, I can add an *Array Modifier* to A with zero count, using *Object Offset* with B and setting *End Cap* also to B.

## Drawback

If A is not centered, scaled or rotated, the two B objects will not align.

## Workaround

I can add a C object and use the *End Cap* method two or more times, with A and B and other objects I like to join together.