# Blender equivalent of components in Sketchup

Tags: mesh

I have used sketchup before. I want to know can we make components or similar feature or addon available. In sketchup if we make a object components and make several copies of that object and if edit a single object of that component it will affects to all the components we have made with that main object. for the reference how the component works https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rKhRDvpn_DU

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a **linked duplicate**. Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> instead of <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> when duplicating and I believe that you will have what you are looking for. Editing any individual object will change them all.

For more info on duplicating see the docs:

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/duplicate.html

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/duplicate_linked.html

Comment: Thanks thats what im looking for. One more question can we divide as u can see the reference video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XmJUPXC9gAA

Comment: You can't by default, but that is an add-on that wouldn't be too difficult to write. I don't see how it is that useful though when we have the array modifier.

Comment: If there is any addon available plz share the name or the link & can i post a new question with this topic

Comment: Yes, you could ask a new question for that (probably a better thing for BlenderArtists), but there isn't already an add-on for it so someone would have to develop it. I could do it pretty easily, but I'm super busy right now :-|

Answer (score 1):

As the answer from JakeD stated, you can **Link Objects** in blender. But the functionality in sketchup allows you to **encapsulate** those objects (you can have **components inside components** and go on. In blender **you can´t have objects inside the mesh** (As far as I know).

**But** in Blender 2.8, **you have collections**, which is some kind of layers, and allows you to have **Collections inside collections** and them you can have an Colletion Instance, Which **will get closer to the nested Component system of Sketchup**!

When using a **Collection Instance**, when you change the main collection **all others instance collections get changed**!

Comment: You could already do this before 2.8 in Blender, it was called groups and Group Dupligroups https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47295/sketchup-like-components-case-study-is-it-in-or-even-feasible/