# Blender equivalent of divider in Sketchup

Tags: add-on

Can we divide objects as you can see the reference video. Is there any addon available similar to the reference video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XmJUPXC9gAA

Comment: Consider using an array modifier... Will that get you where you need to go? You can certainly control replication and distance intervals...

Comment: @rcgauer Yes, that's what I recommended [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/67396/28015), but atek apparently wants this exact feature.