# Multiple animations and rotations on a grouped object

Tags: animation, groups

Still trying to learn Blender here so be gentle. I need to do an animation of a propeller aircraft where the plane travels down the runway, the tail lifts up and the plane takes off.

The propellers must, of course, turn the whole time. I have the propeller set up with a looping animation. My issue is that as soon as I put a rotation keyframe on the group for the tail to lift up, my propeller rotation stops.

I am using a model that I got from CG Trader or someplace like that. I tried using an empty and parenting the group to that, but when I do that the model explodes.

I did a similar animation for a nose wheel aircraft and had no issues with the rotation or the parenting. Different model of course.

I am using Blender 2.77. This animation is being done in Cycles, the other one was done in Blender Render.

Is there a way to make a permanent group? In 3ds (I know they are not the same), when you make a group it stays grouped until you un-group it.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Please keep only one question per post so we can focus on a answer at a time. See [my answer here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47295/sketchup-like-components-case-study-is-it-in-or-even-feasible) about creating groups and related workflow in Blender

Comment: Please edit your question and post more information about your scene and how you are animating it. Show some screenshots and settings, and possibly post a link to your Blend file. It's impossible to help with this little info