# How to lock group

Tags: workflow, groups

Is there any locking of group. When we make a group and after selecting one part of the group the entire group does not move until Press Shit+G -> Group then its move. Or i have to go in the outliner and then click the select the group. Is there any method or addon that can lock all the object which ever part is select the entire group should move without going the process. (Pressing Shift+G -> group). Any suggestion or help Thanks

If i have square triangle and circle. Im a graphic designer i use coreldraw when i press group the selected object get group and when i click on any one object if it is triangle or square or circle the entire group moves If i hold ctrl and press any one only that object is move and in the above mention method it does not.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can instanciate the group, and move the instance as a whole. `Shift + A` in the 3D Viewport -> Group Instance -> Choose your group

Comment: @aliasguru I think you did not get me what i mean. I have edited my question. If i have square triangle and circle. Im a graphic designer i use coreldraw when i press group the selected object get group and when i click on any one object if it is triangle or square or circle the entire group moves and in the above mention method it does not.

Comment: He got what you mean alright, but you did not understand his answer, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47295/sketchup-like-components-case-study-is-it-in-or-even-feasible/47311#47311

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos have a look at leon cheung answer thats what i need and he understood what i needed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set a custom keymap item for faster operation like that:

1. Go to **File** > **User Preferences**, switch to **Input** tab, expand *3D View* > *Object Mode*:
   [image]
2. Scroll down to the bottom of that category, find **Add New** button and click:
   [image]
3. Define a new map item by setting parameters as shown below:
   [image]

Here I define it with RMB double click, but you can always set another map as you want, as long as no conflicts with any other existing shortcuts. Don't forget clicking **Save User Settings** button when it's done.

I hope it can finally be faster and efficient enough:
[image]

Comment: Never even knew I could do this. Setting up right now!! thx

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried creating a **"null object / empty"**  and parenting your meshes to the null/empty?

You can then move the null object (empty) around and the group would move.

Note: This concept is something I have used in various other software too, especially while controlling camera rigs. It might not be the best method, but it works.

[image: Parenting to a null to have free group movement]

Comment: You aren't adding empty to the group, you parented mesh objects to the empty.

Comment: @MrZak - Thank you for pointing it out. I realized I was using the "grouping" word a bit loosely while it has a completely different meaning in Blender probably. I have edited my answer to better reflect what I am doing. Hope this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

What it comes down to is this:
In CorelDRAW, when objects are grouped together, the group automatically becomes the parent of its objects.

Not so in Blender where groups are more of an organizational concept. To get behaviour similar to what CorelDRAW exhibits, you need the empty cited in the previous answer. It then can be made the parent and you'll get what you're looking for.

Another way to achieve this 'group' behaviour is to use Ctrl-J to join your objects into one object. Then you would use Edit Mode to move individual 'objects' (which are actually discrete vertex meshes rather than objects in this case).

Hint: While in Edit Mode, hover your mouse pointer over a discrete mesh and hit Ctrl-L to select.

Comment: But the problem comes when it have many modifier and material used to different objects and not to simple object