# How to duplicate the empty

Tags: parent

I have 3 object and group. Added an empty and parent to it. Holding the empty i can move the complete group. I can select the group and empty and press shit+D it duplicate. But how can i duplicate the complete group made with the empty in complex scene. When i select the empty i can just move complete group but when press shift+D it duplicate only the empty not the object which are parent to it. For example given below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Following [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78720/how-to-lock-group) I stil think you don't know how to properly use groups, and you should probably be [using dupligroups](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47295/sketchup-like-components-case-study-is-it-in-or-even-feasible/47311#47311) instead

Comment: In a complex scene, you can just select the empty and Shift + G to select the group.  From there you can duplicate as many times as you want.

Comment: @bertmoog When we select the empty the object in the parent moves with it. But when try to duplicate the selected empty it duplicate only the empty and not the object which are with the empty. So i need to duplicate the empty with the object holding the empty (in complex scene)

Comment: I'm just pointing out that since you grouped the objects, you can select the entire group and thus you *can* duplicate the entire group after selection... without having to Border select anything.

Comment: @bertmoog The 1st time is just to select. After making few duplicate and from that if i select an empty and want to duplicate, it duplicate only the empty not the object which are present with the empty

Answer (score 3):

It is called [Dupligroup](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/duplication/dupligroup.html). After assigning a [group](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/relations/groups.html) to an object/s, add an empty and go to the object properties. Under duplication you will find a group option, enable it and then select the group. Every object in the group (and others added later) will be duplicated around the empty.

[image: dupligroup settings]

Comment: I think u did not get my question. In the Archimesh Addon when we add a window or door with the empty we get the door and window. And after arranging to the wall if we need another window beside it. Click the empty if we try to duplicate to have another widow we cant get we get just the empty. So same i want to duplicate the window selecting the empty.

Comment: While you hadn't mentioned using the archmesh addon, the parts it creates are made of several objects, you need to select and duplicate all of them together. To work with this answer, select all of the window objects and add them to a group called window, then add an empty and set it to duplicate the window group and then you only duplicate the empty to duplicate the whole window and any changes made to the original window will affect all of them.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want a method to select all that which is a child of the empty.

This can be done trhough the outliner, right clicking on the mepty and selecting select hierarchy, or with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> which expands your selectiong one hierarchy level.

Comment: Yeah u did not get what i mean. When we select the empty the object in the parent moves with it. But when try to duplicate the selected empty it duplicate only the empty and not the object which are with the empty. So i need to duplicate the empty with the object.