# Real-time symmetrical modeling with distinct objects in Blender

Tags: modeling, modifiers, groups

I would like to create a 3D model that has a wide variety of individually selectable objects on the right side of the x-axis, and then all of those same objects mirrored dynamically across to the other side of the x-axis. How do I do it?

**What I want to achieve**

1. Create an object with an origin at 0,0,0 and no parts jutting into the left side of the x-axis.
2. Create another object (say, a cube) somewhere on the right side of the x-axis.
3. Somehow create an association between these two objects that lets me still select them easily later.
4. Apply a mirror modifier to the association.
5. Create more objects on the right side of the x-axis and add them to the association so that they are also mirrored on the other side of the x-axis.
6. Add objects, move objects, change objects, and have them update in real time across the axis.

**What I've tried**
 - Grouping objects and then putting a modifier on the group (I wasn't able to get this to work)
 - Ctrl+J to join the meshes (but then I can't select them easily individually)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what [Groups and Group Instances](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47295/sketchup-like-components-case-study-is-it-in-or-even-feasible) are for, you just don't add modifiers to them.

[image]

Create your selection of objects you want to belong to this symmetry group, then group them together with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>. Give it a descriptive name

Now from the *Add* menu add a new group instance with the previously given name. Scale it a factor of -1 in X so it becomes mirrored.

You may optionally want to make the instance non selectable in the *Outliner* so it doesn't accidentally get in the way.

Now freely work on your original group of objects and see them symetrized automatically. Whenever you feel like adding a new one just link it to the existing group.

You can do this by selecting any new objects, then <kbd>Shift</kbd> selecting one already belonging to the group so it remains the active one. Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> > *Make Links* > *Group*.

[image]

Comment: This works reeeally well and is exactly what I was hoping to be able to do. Thank you!