# How to dupliframe several objects

Tags: modeling, objects

I have a basic wall lamp made of 3 objects:
- a support
- a light bulb (emissive half-sphere)
- a Blender point lamp

I would like to duplicate this wall lamp along a curve.

I used dupliframe as I don’t want objects to be deformed along the curve.

I made the light bulb and the point lamp as children of the support, then the support as children of the curve. In the support object properties I used duplicate/frames. But only the support us duplicated, not the light bulb and the point lamp.

What is the right way to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: I think you need [Group Instances](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47295/sketchup-like-components-case-study-is-it-in-or-even-feasible)