# Groups: Ok, I give

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

Looking for an answer but cannot find one so far...

So, ok... Blender doesn't do traditional "groups".

*Most very program I've ever used* lets you hit "ctrl-g" or something which results in a single manipulable entity.

Blender... not so. I can't seem to figure out what the heck I need to do, for example, to click on 5 things, "group" them, go do some other stuff, then come back, click on the "group", and rotate, move, or whatever.

What's the secret?

Comment: This is one of the major changes between 2.79 and 2.8, so I guess you had better include the version in your question

Comment: Hey Robin - I hope that's good news... I have both, but am really liking 2.8, so let's go with 2.8!

(This question was largely based on what seemed to be workarounds for doing this in 2.79)

Cheers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sketchup-like components (case study) - is it in? or even feasible?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47295/sketchup-like-components-case-study-is-it-in-or-even-feasible)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Well... that was posted 2+ years ago, so if it's changed in 2.8, it may not be a duplicate.

And, I hope it's not, because that's a heck of a lot of stuff to do just to accomplish what a quick ctrl-g does in like 95% of other software....

Comment: In 2.8 if you want to select the whole group of an object, click on one of its objects then press shift G > Collection. In the Outliner you can left click on the group name and choose select... but it would be logical that you could select the whole group with a simple click... I don't know everything about 2.8 though

Comment: Ok, looks like the process (in 2.8, anyway) is ctrl-j in object mode to "join", and "P > By Loose Parts" in edit mode to... unjoin.

Not sure how the thinking goes behind this...

Comment: @RobinBetts - can you elaborate on the changes? Still haven't found a way to do this.

Comment: @moonboots - That "loose parts" thing isn't really working since it breaks the object down way more than just into the joined components.

Comment: (I suspect the the things you want to do might be best achieved by temporarily parenting your objects to an empty.) I know that 2.79's Groups and Layers have been taken under the umbrella of 'Collections'... and I've read and watched what I can about them, but I don't have enough experience using them to give what would qualify as an answer.. I was hoping for one myself :)