# Understanding blender collection, instancing from Sketchup side of view

Tags: collections

I'm trying to migrate to Blender from Sketchup.

There, instancing is managed simply by 'group' and 'component'.

Groups are just separate coordinate system while components make object an instance. So when you want to separate singular object you make group, else to make linked objects you make component. Groups can have components and components also do. There is no depth restriction so a group can have groups which have component which have another components that have a group, and so on.

This kind of structuring is very crucial in architectural modeling as they tend to have duplicated objects and become very hierarchical.

I've read this and that about blender instancing, grouping, tied playing with boxes for days but still things are not clear. I think one of the cause is that parenting and grouping is separate in Blender.

So I'm asking here hopping someone could give a golden answer (once again) that would weave everything vividly and reveal real power of Blender specific hierarchy structure represented by 'collection'.

Is there anyone coming from Sketchup side and managed to understand instancing in Blender? How should I reroute my thinking?

Comment: Collections are a _very_ general mechanism for grouping, used in many ways in Blender, much like a directory system with symbolic linking.. so objects can be linked to more than one collection, collections can be nested, and so on. Maybe what you're looking for is [Collection Instances](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/163215/35559)