# propagate object manipulations across multiple similar objects

Tags: modeling

I'm working on a model as I'm learning Blender for educational purposes. I have a collection of objects that together make up the "pillar" collection. I'm going to duplicate this collection multiple times (in the below screenshot I did it once already, for testing purposes).

However, I will continue to manipulate all objects within this base collection going forward, and I want all manipulations to propagate to all the duplicate collections.

I've read about – and played around with – linking and child-parent relationships, but I have yet to find a solution that allows me to pick one whole collection as the base model, and then see any changes made to that collection applied to all other relevant collections.

Is this possible? If it is, can I do it within a single `.blend` file, or does it require me linking another blend file into this one?

[image]

Comment: Sounds like what [Collection instances](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47295/sketchup-like-components-case-study-is-it-in-or-even-feasible/47311#47311) and object duplicates are for

Comment: Thank you @DuarteFarrajotaRamos that seems to be exactly what I was looking for, and it works great so far.