# Is there a way to manipulate objects as group in Blender 2.8?

Tags: collections

I grouped objects in Collection. But I can't find a way to select collection as 'one object' and let's say center it.

Comment: Have you tried right-clicking the collection in the Outliner and selecting *Select Hiearchy"?

Comment: You can create collection instances. An instance can be manipulated as one object and modified from the original collection.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47295/sketchup-like-components-case-study-is-it-in-or-even-feasible/47311

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A collection allows to create collection instances.

[image]

As [p2or](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/3710/p2or) said in comments, you can also in 3D view <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, then *'collection instance'* and choose the collection you want to instanciate.

Once done, you use the instance as one object:

On the right here the original collection, on the left, the instance that you can manipulate as if it is an object:

[image]

You can "edit" the instance from its base collection:

Either manipulating the individual objects:

[image]

Or modifying them in edit mode:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way is to make an empty and parent the objects into it by using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>