# How to group the house

Tags: objects

what are the steps to group the parts of the house so that I can move it around[image]

Comment: You haven't given enough details to answer that! Is it made of seperate objects, and if so can you show it in Object mode with the Outliner in View Layer mode so that we can see how many parts are involved?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47295/are-groups-or-sketchup-like-components-feasible-in-blender

Comment: you can make the parts of the house become children of an *Empty* object. Make sure the Empty is the *active* object (=usually the last selected object, highlighted in orange), then Ctrl+P. If you move the Empty the rest of the house should move with it.

Comment: Hello Blunder, I selected the house and everything is orange tried Ctrl+P and a box pops up  Set to Parent , Object, Object keep transform, Object without inverse, Vertex and Vertex Triangle. I clicked everyone but the windows and door does not move with the house.