How do you organize your parts to an object? Do I use Emptys? If so, is there a good tutorial?
I was wondering how you guys organize your objects in Blender. For example, a door contains a door knob, hinges, door frame and door. Do you put all of those objects into one collection and assign an empty to them?

Hey, this forum is best for asking a specific question with a specific solution. Broad or opinionated questions like this have a dozen different decent answers. I would recommend the Blender discord server or BlenderArtists for discussions about big-picture workflow tips.

I agree with @Jakemoyo that your question is off-topic for this Q&A site, however the usual method is simply to parent all the door 'furniture' to the door itself.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47295/are-groups-or-sketchup-like-components-feasible-in-blender
